# Regex For MetaTags

Tags: .net, regex

Hello I'm attempting to parse meta tags using the HTML meta code here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16548/HTML-Meta-Tag-Parser

The code works well, but have noted one issue the regex doesn't match with tags without a space before the self close on the HTML tag.

i.e.
 `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.surfstitch.com/product/penny-36-inch-longboard-skateboard-glow" />` Works (Space " />")
 `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.surfstitch.com/product_images/PNYCOMP36105-PENNY-1_180X225.JPG"/>` Doesn't work (No Space "/>")

```
<meta\s*(?:(?:\b(\w|-)+\b\s*(?:=\s*(?:""[^""]*""|'" + "[^']*'|[^""'<> ]+)\s*)?)*)/?\s*>
```

The regex is as per above, Ill keep trying, Ive tried a few mods but still pretty novice at Regex and cannot find an online .NET regex tester that shows results that Im sure that work. i.e. This says no matches when theres heaps: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Thanks

Comment: Avoid parsing html with regex.

Comment: If not Regex then what?